# RangeSlider onFirstChange non-existent property

Tags: qt, qml, rangeslider, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using `RangeSlider` for my project in QML. My range slider code is as follows:

```
 RangeSlider {
     id: rangeSLider
     first.value:  0.0
     second.value: 1.0
     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
     width: 275
     onFirstChanged: console.log("Change")
 }
```

When I run this code, I get an error. The error is:

```
Cannot assign to non-existent property "onFirstChanged"
```

I want to change a text in a parent QML file. So I thought I'd use `onFirstChange` and `onSecondChange` functions to do that, but it did not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It helps other people help you a lot easier. In this case, I'd like to see a QML snippet I could look at using qmlscene (including showing what imports you use, this is important!)

Assuming you are using [QtQuickControls 2's RangeSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html), The `first` and `second` properties are constant. This means that those values themselves do not change, but rather, the members of those properties (e.g. first.value) change instead. So you want to connect the change signal to the `first`/`second`/ instance, rather than on the RangeSlider itself, something like this:

```
RangeSlider {
    from: 1
    to: 100
    first.value: 30
    second.value: 70

    Connections {
        target: first
        onValueChanged: console.log("first.value changed!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the syntax for RangeSlider of **Qt 5.11 (Qt QuickControls 2.4)**:

```
RangeSlider {
    from: 0
    to: 100
    first.value: 25
    second.value: 75
    first.onValueChanged: console.debug("RangeSlider first value is " + first.value)
    second.onValueChanged: console.debug("RangeSlider second value is " + second.value)
}
```

Source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html